# Methods from Class Arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, class

I have several `classes` with a lot of `methods` and `functions`, which normally handles `mx1` `arrays`. For a given `class`:

```
S1.x=randn(m,1);
S1+2*randn(m,1); % Plus Override
S1.smooth; % Class Methods
S1.detrend;
```

Now i wish to handle `class` `arrays` for the same given `class`, on a way like this;

```
S=[S1 S2 S3 S4];
S.smooth; % Methods for Class Array
S.detrend;
```

***Question***: 
**Is there a simple way for doing this, without rewritting all the `functions` implementing the `class` `properties`  and `methods`?**

I am looking for some specific addition, redefinition, piece of code, trick, etc. in order to do that in a clean way. The purpose of this is *code functionality*, not *performance* -the few performance critical functions are already vectorized-.

Greetings,

Comment: `S1, S2, S3, S4` are instances of different classes, or of same class?

Comment: Yes. the class is the same.

Answer (score 2):

How about that:

```
classdef TestClass
   methods
       function smooth(obj)
           if numel(obj) == 1
               disp('Hello')
           else
               for i=1:numel(obj)
                   obj(i).smooth;
               end
           end

       end
   end
end
```

Called as follow:

```
>> t1 = TestClass;
>> t1.smooth
Hello


>> t2 = [TestClass TestClass TestClass];    
>> t2.smooth
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

If you really wanted to you should also be able to overload the [subsref](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) operator to automatically do that on all your methods (it gives you access to the `.` operator) . However in my experience overloading `subsref` correctly is not straight forward and might be more effort than what is worth.

Here is an example of this idea. It's simplistic and you will likely will need further refinement on your part but should get you started. Note the cheer amount of hackery :)

```
classdef TestClass
properties
    Value
end

methods        
    function obj = TestClass(x)
        obj.Value = x;
    end

    function smooth(obj)
        fprintf('I am %d\n', obj.Value)
    end

    function res = opposite(obj)
        res = -obj.Value;
    end

    function [res1,res2,res3] = test(obj)
        res1 = obj.Value;
        res2 = res1*res1;
        res3 = res2*res1;
    end

    function varargout = subsref(A,S)
        if numel(A) > 1 && strcmp(S(1).type, '.')
            if nargout == 0
                feval(S.subs, A(1));
            else
                nout = nargout(['TestClass>TestClass.' S.subs]);
                if nout < 0
                    nout = -nout;
                end
                if nout == 0
                    arrayfun(@(x)feval(S.subs, x), A);
                    varargout = cell(1, nargout);
                else
                    for i=1:nargout                            
                        [output{1:nout}] = feval(S.subs, A(i));
                        varargout{i} = output;
                        output = {};
                    end
                end

            end
        else
            if nargout == 0
                builtin('subsref', A, S);
            else
                varargout{:} = builtin('subsref', A, S);
            end
        end
    end        
end
```

Example of use:

```
>> t1 = TestClass(5);
>> t1.smooth;
I am 5

>> t2 = [TestClass(1) TestClass(2) TestClass(3)];
>> t2(2).smooth;
I am 2
>> t2.smooth;
I am 1
I am 2
I am 3
>> t2(1:2).smooth
I am 1
I am 2
>> t2(2:3).smooth
I am 2
I am 3
>> t2([1 3]).smooth
I am 1
I am 3
>> t2.test

ans = 

    [1]    [1]    [1]


ans = 

    [2]    [4]    [8]


ans = 

    [3]    [9]    [27]
```

Comment: Thank you for the functional example code. Because i have so many of these functions, i am avoiding at all cost the modification of all them through a `for` cycle plus testing condition.  And i am still unclear how to overload the `subsref`operator or any other for achieving this. Though it is a big hint.

Comment: Yes it don't seems to be straightforward at all.... But it is a kind of solution that will leave the rest of the code intact or with little modifications...

Comment: @hypfco I've updated the solution, hope that helps. you'd need to think what you want to do when the methods return a value, multiple values, no value, has have variable number of outputs, access to properties, correct handling of public/private method etc. Anyway I thinkl that should give you enough to work with :)

Comment: Thanks. This is the kind of solution i was looking for.... I will check the operation and mark the question as solved. And regarding the output, i fear it will be even simpler, because the functions has no outputs...